# My object is undefined in componentdidmount after calling mapdispatchtoprops to dispatch a thunk

Tags: react-native, components

I am trying to render data automatically to my component when i render it.
I have fired off a thunk in mapDispatchToProps which gets data from my Firebase Database and adds it to my redux state. I have set up my component did mount to trigger the dispatch correctly as can be seen in my [redux log.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJsoP.png)

As you can see the object is returning undefined, however if I trigger these actions by the buttons in my simulator it returns the object fine. I know it's to do with the component lifecycle, should I be doing something in componentwillreceive props before componentdidmount?

Here is my componentdidmount, mapdispatchtoprops and mapstatetoprops.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { onMountFetchUsers } = this.props
    onMountFetchUsers()
    const nameParsed = JSON.stringify(this.props.names)
    console.log("nameParsed =" + nameParsed);
}
```